# PLC Audio Transceiver

Tags: audio, analog, power-line-communication

So the idea of my project is to simply pass through an audio signal which is recorded using a microphone and then transmit it to the power line and on the receiver part the audio will be played by a speaker. The plan is for the PLC modem i will be using LM1893. First question : have i choose the right IC for the project? and the second one is does anyone have done some similar project to mine and willing to share their work? all replies are appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you know that this is an intercomputer data transmission line interface, it sends and receives serial data stream which is inputted and outputted by a serial data port of a computer.

The datasheet http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/nationalsemiconductor/DS006750.PDF claims several kilobits per second are transferrable, but the actual performance depends on line properties and noise environment. It can be as slow as few hundred bits per second.

LM1893 is too slow for real time transmission of CD-record quality audio. But the speed can be enough for transferring a pre-recorded audio file if the file is small enough when compared to the allowed transmission time. Check how big files you have and calculate how much time it takes

The available bitrate depends on the distance, line properties and noise environment, it cannot be declared beforehand. It can be tested in practice. The datasheet gives some examples

Highly compressed speech probably can be transferred in real time. I bet nobody recognizes any fine speech tone details because the available data rate is so slow. It surely resembles speech synthesizer.

The IC can be used in analog mode. It's modulator-demodulator can be used in FM-transmission of audio. It's said in the datasheet. That can be your other possibility, a realistic one.

I guess power lines have now and then noise peaks which can be heard in analog audio transmission as clicks, but which in data transmission cause only slowness because a missed chunk must be repeated. Error detection codes reveal the need of new attempt. That's all about coding, protocol and software which is beyond the scope of this answer.